# Doctrine mapping with multiple mapped by on same field

Tags: symfony, database-design, doctrine-orm, entity

I'm having a hard time figuring how to make this work. I have a generic user entity which can represent two types of users(artist and booker). Now, i have a booking request which holds information about artist and booker both.

I have this by now:

```
//Boooking request entity

<many-to-one field="artist" target-entity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User" inversed-by="bookingRequestArtist">
  <join-column name="artist_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one field="booker" target-entity="App\UserBundle\Entity\User" inversed-by="bookingRequestBooker">
  <join-column name="booker_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
</many-to-one>

//Generic user entity
<one-to-many field="bookingRequestArtist" target-entity="App\BookingBundle\Entity\BookingRequest" mapped-by="????" />
```

I'm wondering how to organize User entity so it has booking request field since i'm dealing with two types of users and two fields would be redundant. Is it possible to achieve a structure where something like $user->getBookigRequest() is possible with two types of users who share same booking request?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need single table inheritance. You want to have multiple entities but one table.
Check [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) out.

Comment: Tried to implement with base user class as superclass of artist and booker but it added pretty much undesirable level of complexity. Thx for suggestion tho

Comment: @3ND That is the only way I can think of to achieve what you require. :)